# MySql on Yosemite can't be stopped through control panel if autostarted at start up

Tags: mysql, osx-yosemite

After installing the script found at [How to auto-load MySQL on startup on OS X Yosemite / El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476391/how-to-auto-load-mysql-on-startup-on-osx-yosemite), MySql starts automatically at system reboot of Yosemite, but now it impossible to stop it using the control panel in system preferences

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands in terminal instead of the control panel for now:

`sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`

`sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop`

I believe installing the latest version of MySQL will fix the GUI issue:
http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25954335/922522